# How to minimize the query to reduce waiting time

Tags: sql

i have update query but when i execute the quesry it take a long time to execute until it success. i dont know whats wrong. i run in dbeaver is there anyway to execute the quesry without waiting too long ?

```
update m_deposit_account_term_and_preclosure
    set last_accrued_amount = (select amount from acc_gl_journal_entry where entry_date = (select max(entry_date) from acc_gl_journal_entry) and entity_id = sa.id and type_enum = 2 and description = 'Accrual Deposit Interest Expense End Of Month')
from m_savings_account sa
where sa.id = m_deposit_account_term_and_preclosure.savings_account_id;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? What does this have to do with DBeaver (which is an IDE)?

Comment: How many records being updated? and how many records are there in both tables?

Comment: I removed the *multiple* database tags. Please tag the specific database.

Comment: thanks for the coment, i already solve it .. with join

Comment: @AlexsandroSiregar Please consider accepting the ANSWER as a kindness to Mr. Brandt.

Answer (score 1):

As written, the update is executing the subquery on a row by row basis. That's going to be very slow, indeed.

Changing to a set-based operation by joining your tables first will improve overall performance, but if you have a lot of rows to update, it could still take a long time. Adding a `WHERE` clause will help, but it's entirely dependent on your tables.

MySQL:

```
UPDATE 
  m_deposit_account_term_and_preclosure as da
  JOIN
  m_savings_account as sa
    ON sa.id = da.savings_account_id
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT 
        entity_id,
        amount
      FROM acc_gl_journal_entry
      WHERE entry_date = (
          SELECT max(entry_date)
          FROM acc_gl_journal_entry
          )
        AND entity_id = sa.id
        AND type_enum = 2
        AND description = 'Accrual Deposit Interest Expense End Of Month'
    ) as amt
SET da.last_accrued_amount = amt.amount
WHERE da.last_accrued_amount <> amt.amount;
```

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE da
SET last_accrued_amount = amt.amount
FROM
  m_deposit_account_term_and_preclosure as da
  JOIN
  m_savings_account as sa
    ON sa.id = da.savings_account_id
  JOIN
    (
      SELECT 
        entity_id,
        amount
      FROM acc_gl_journal_entry
      WHERE entry_date = (
          SELECT max(entry_date)
          FROM acc_gl_journal_entry
          )
        AND entity_id = sa.id
        AND type_enum = 2
        AND description = 'Accrual Deposit Interest Expense End Of Month'
    ) as amt
WHERE da.last_accrued_amount <> amt.amount;
```